# What is the age of the youngest known Bitcoin developer?

Tags: development

What is the youngest age of someone known to have submitted a Pull Request to Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Corallo (https://github.com/TheBlueMatt) was 18 when he started contributing to Bitcoin Core (back then just called Bitcoin).

At that age, he added support for UPnP, wrote the first dynamic DNS seeder, improved the build system, introduced wallet encryption, added debian package building, and fixed various bugs.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/whitj00

Whit Jackson, 15 is the youngest I can find. Github does not list the ages of PR authors:)

http://www.coindesk.com/15-year-old-developer-ethereum-whit-jackson/

edit: I am not sure of his exact birthday. He may have been 14 when submitting this PR for bitcoin.org:

https://github.com/whitj00/bitcoin.org/commit/b3ef809c7c63c9ededa4f4ad40ef5ff314434fe8

Comment: Note question was about Bitcoin Core. I see Ethereum and bitcoin.org (the website) in the answer.

Comment: -1 As already implied by Jannes, it seems to me that Whit Jackson has not submitted a PR to Bitcoin Core. So, strictly spoken this answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: I marked the Pieter Wuille answer as correct because I technically did say core, however this answer was interesting too. It is nice to see developers get involved at such a young age!